# Set custom variable in capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano

I was using capistrano 2 with my php project, where I used to define custom variables like this:

```
set :app_environment, "test"
```

And then I accessed it in my deploy tasks, e.g.:

```
run "echo '#{app_environment}' > #{releases_path}/#{release_name}/protected/config/mode.php"
```

Now in capistrano 3 I define this variable in my stage-specific config files. But I don't have them defined in my tasks:

```
undefined local variable or method `app_environment' for #<SSHKit::Backend::Netssh:0x007f92323d6988> config/deploy.rb:28:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Unfortunately there's not much documentation on the newest version of capistrano and I'm not quite familiar with ruby, so I don't see the way how to do that properly.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The code should read:

```
run "echo '#{fetch(:app_environment)}' > #{releases_path}/#{fetch(:release_name)}/protected/config/mode.php"
```

Although even that is incorrect as `run()` doesn't exist in Cap3, it's now `execute()`, so:

```
execute "echo '#{fetch(:app_environment)}' > #{releases_path}/#{fetch(:release_name)}/protected/config/mode.php"
```

Beware constructing your command like this nothing will use the command map, or respect the `within()`, `as()` or `with()` constructs.

Comment: Thank you! I'm aware about how command execution has changed in cap3 and i've already updated my code. There's no information on 'fetch' method on capistrano website though (guess i looked through it a lot of times and couldn't have missed it).

Comment: The point is that `set()` and `fetch()` are internal APIs. The reasons for using them for *any* variable don't exist in v3, so unless you REALLY need the deferred evaluation, you should just use regular variables.

Answer (score 18):

This is now achieved via 'fetch':

```
fetch(:app_environment)
```